# Position div under floated div

Tags: html, css

A simple problem today but can't seem to find the solution. I have four divs - I would like #down to be placed directly below #up, but for the life of my can't figure it out. Here is my CSS and HTML.

[image]

```css
#up {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
}
#down {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999999;
  float: left;
}
#mid {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #999999;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="up"></div>
<div id="mid"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="down"></div>
```

Elements must remain floated left.

Comment: Not gonna happen with your current markup structure. You'll need a more elaborate grid with a nested column.

Comment: Just use http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: how about keeping first div with the same height and deviding it in 2 vertical divs ?

Comment: Will probably have to do that Rayon, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe try with an additional div to get both up and down together?

```
<div id="up_down">
<div id="up"></div>
<div id="down"></div></div>
<div id="mid"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

And you will changed your css to :

```
up_down{
width: 33.3%;
height: 200px;
}

#up {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
background: #CCCCCC;
float: left;
}
#down {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
background: #999999;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, and also thanks to all who suggested the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than working with floats, you might consider simply setting the display attribute of the middle divs to "inline-block". Remember that be default, div elements have a block display, which means that they take up the entire width of its parent element, even if its width is less than the parent width. inline blocks on the other hand fit together like puzzle pieces and flow horizontally rather than vertically.

Answer (score 1):

As @isherwoord says in the first comment, wrap div#up and div#down together in another div, forexample div#column

(I hope you don't mind the HAML way of writing HTML.)

```
div#column
  div#up
  div#down

div#middle
div#right
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the heights/widths you can just set the top position of #down with `position:relative;top:-100px;` to pull it back up.

Example:

```css
#up {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
}
#down {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999999;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  top:-100px;
}
#mid {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #999999;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="up"></div>
<div id="mid"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="down"></div>
```

Comment: I think something was with my browser, it works now and i don't see you made any changes